# Removing @'s in wordwrapped VIM text

Tags: vim, macvim

Lines in VIM that wordwrapped on show @ on that line instead of the text if any part of the text is off-screen.  How do I get it so I can see partial wordwrapped text like other editors?

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, it's only when you have a very long line and it wraps past the bottom of the viewable area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.vimrc or _vimrc:

```
set display=lastline
```

See

```
:help 'display'
```

for more information.

Comment: you might want `set display+=lastline` in the unlikely situation in which you already have the `uhex` option set.